# Objects filter - need advise

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Let's say I have three models:

```
class ONE (models.Model):
    [some awesome stuff]

class TWO (models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(ONE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    [other stuff]

class THREE (models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(ONE)
    [stuff and whatnot]
```

The view looks currently like this:

```
def my_view(request, username, template_name='view.html'):
    current_user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    two = TWO.objects.filter(user_id=current_user)
    three = THREE.objects.filter(one_id=two)

    data = {
        'user': current_user, 
        'two': two,
        'three': three
    }

    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

Database entries are (**this is simplified**; there is more data in each table):

```
Table ONE
----------
id=1
id=2
id=3

Table TWO
----------
one_id=1; user_id=1
one_id=2; user_id=1
one_id=3; user_id=1

Table THREE
----------
one_id=1
one_id=2
one_id=3
```

With the above view I'm not able to display all entries from table THREE where user_id=1 from table TWO.

Error message = `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

I tried to use `three = THREE.objects.filter(one_id__in=two)` but that doesn't display anything on the html page. No error message either.

HTML:

```
{% for two in two %}
    <p>{{ two.one }}</p> <!-- that works! -->
{% endfor %}
{% for three in three %}
<ul>
    <li>{{ three }}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a filter option for my needs?

Comment: What's the `response` variable looks like?

Comment: That was an error. `response` == `two`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to correct `__in` filter. The argument must be the `list` instance, not `QuerySet`:

```
two = TWO.objects.filter(user_id=current_user)
two_ids = two.values_list('id', flat=True).distinct('id')
three = THREE.objects.filter(one_id__in=two_ids)
```

`distinct` here is not required but strongly recommended.

See more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct